# uploading tracks to soundcloud from ableton

Tags: sound-design, sound

im trying to upload a track from ableton 8 live to soundcloud. it will only get up to 20 or 50 percent than it goes back down to 1 percent, ive uploaded tracks before and never had this problem so what do i need to do now.

Comment: Maybe there's an error with ableton build-in soundcloud API. 
Best bet would be to update Live to latest version

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just try to bounce the track out of ableton and then upload it to the website :)
Cheers!